# RestTemplate.exchange long delay

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, resttemplate

Our Spring application is using RestTemplate to send HTTP 1.1 requests to web service endpoints via the exchange() method.  99.8% of the time this works fine, but in 0.2% of cases this results in a long (10-180 seconds) delay between when restTemplate.exchange() is called and when our load balancer logs the HTTP request (which is then forwarded to the web service).  The restTemplate is initialized without an argument specifying an alternate ClientHttpRequestFactory, so I know this code is not taking advantage of connection pooling, e.g. by initializing it like the following:

```
restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory())
```

Does this logically explain the symptom I'm describing, or should I keep investigating?

This is the code fragment, with the last line to .exchange() producing the slow performance a small % of the time.

```
private <T> ResponseEntity<T> request(String project, 
    String url, 
    HttpMethod method, 
    HttpEntity<String> request, 
    ClientHttpRequestInterceptor moduleInterceptor, 
    ParameterizedTypeReference<T> parameterizedTypeReference) {

    log.info("request(): url - {}", url);
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
    if (moduleInterceptor != null) {
        interceptors.add(moduleInterceptor);
    }
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
    try {
        ResponseEntity<T> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, method, request, parameterizedTypeReference);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?